# Are the Russian уж (a kind of snake) and узко (narrow) related?

Tags: etymology, russian

According to Mallory we have the following PIE words:

***a̯enghu̯is*** snake (> уж)

***a̯enĝhus*** narrow (> узко)

***a̯enĝhnos*** fear, constriction (> ужас)

This hints at that the words could be related if the exact value of the g was determined wrongly.

I also wonder whether the following words are related:

***e̯oğhis*** snake, serpent (in Fortson, ***e̯eĝhu̯is***). Mallory claims this is unrelated to the ***a̯enghu̯is***. Fortson claims it is related to the following entry and reconstructs the same consonant in the root. Mallory claims that the "traditional school" derived hedgehog as "snake-eater". The Brill etymological dictionary of Latin reconstructs the initial a̯- here and links this root to the ***a̯nğhis***, claiming that the -n- infix appeared in it due to analogy.

***e̯eĝhis*** hedgehog (> russ. ёж, eng. hedgehog)

***e̯eĝhs*** out

***e̯eĝherom*** lake (> russ. озеро)

If ***e̯oghu̯is***, it could be connected to ***e̯eghu̯ti*** drinks

Comment: You misrepresent de Vaan 2008. Here's what he says, "PIE *h2(e)ngwh-i- 'snake'." Also, "Maybe *n was introduced into this stem by analogy with verbs for 'to twist, wind'." The keyword here is **maybe**.

Comment: What exactly is Mallory? Fortson? Page numbers? cf. Mallory and Adams 2006 *h1ogwhis 'snake' (pp. 146-147).

Comment: @Alex B. yes I am referring to Mellory & Adams, exactly what you have mentioned.

Comment: Could you update your question? With proper referencing, year, page numbers, **asterisked** reconstructed forms?